# Selecting rows by members of a list contained in a cell

Tags: python, pandas, selection, dataframe

In my dataframe I have a column that contains lists of items. I would like to select only those rows that contain all or several items. At least matching a list would be great.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,[2,3,8]]], columns=['a','b'])
df
```

I have tried the following:

```
 df[df['b'] == [2,3,8]]
 df[[2,3,8] in df['b']] # and etc.
```

I feel blindfolded here...

To FooBar:

I am doing scientific fields analysis. The list contains codes of different scientific fields. Where row represents cases, when these scientific fields are coocuring. I can keep list members in different columns, but the problem is that the number of coocuring fields is changing. Therefore I thought that it is ok to keep a list in  a cell.

Comment: This setup (having the list as a single column) is not standard and has many downsides. Are you aware of the pro and cons of this decision and purposefully set up your database like this? If not, share more about your ultimate goal or what kind of data you're trying to organize, and we may suggest better database strategies.

Comment: (you can see the awkwardness of the setup by how complicated the answers are - this should usually be a piece of cake)

Comment: @FooBar you are right - many elements in one cell is one of `antipattern` described in book [SQL Antipatterns](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557)

Comment: @Aidis I added an answer that will change your data into a more suitable format. I hope that having the two keys that distinguish standard data and your scientific fields are satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to compare tuples

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, (2,3,8)],
    [2, (12,13,18)],
    [3, (2,3,8)],
    [4, (1,2,3,8,10)],
    [5, (8,3,2)],
]

#----------------------------------------------

df_tuple = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['a','b'])

print '\n DataFrame with tuples \n'
print df_tuple

print '\n tuple == : \n'

print df_tuple['b'] == (2,3,8)
print df_tuple[ df_tuple['b'] == (2,3,8) ]

print '\n tuple eq() : \n'

print df_tuple['b'].eq((2,3,8))
print df_tuple[ df_tuple['b'].eq((2,3,8)) ]

#----------------------------------------------
```

result

```
 DataFrame with tuples 

   a                 b
0  1         (2, 3, 8)
1  2      (12, 13, 18)
2  3         (2, 3, 8)
3  4  (1, 2, 3, 8, 10)
4  5         (8, 3, 2)

 tuple == : 

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
   a          b
0  1  (2, 3, 8)
2  3  (2, 3, 8)

 tuple eq() : 

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
   a          b
0  1  (2, 3, 8)
2  3  (2, 3, 8)
```

But there is the problem to compare lists and I don't know why.

But you need rows with all or several items from list `[2,3,8]` so I would use `apply()`with own function.

```
import pandas as pd

#----------------------------------------------

data = [
    [1, [2,3,8]],
    [2, [12,13,18]],
    [3, [2,3,8]],
    [4, [1,2,3,8,10]],
    [5, [8,3,2]],
]

#----------------------------------------------

df_list = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['a','b'])

print '\n DataFrame with lists \n'
print df_list

print '\n test: \n'

# test if any element from data list is in [2,3,8]
def test(data):
    return any( x in [2,3,8] for x in data )

print df_list['b'].apply(test)
print df_list[ df_list['b'].apply(test) ]

#----------------------------------------------
```

result

```
 DataFrame with lists 

   a                 b
0  1         [2, 3, 8]
1  2      [12, 13, 18]
2  3         [2, 3, 8]
3  4  [1, 2, 3, 8, 10]
4  5         [8, 3, 2]

 test: 

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
   a                 b
0  1         [2, 3, 8]
2  3         [2, 3, 8]
3  4  [1, 2, 3, 8, 10]
4  5         [8, 3, 2]
```

More useful version - with second argument:

`test_any` return `True` if **any** element from **data** list is on **expected** list

```
def test_any(data, expected):
    return any( x in expected for x in data )

print df_list['b'].apply(lambda x:test_any(x,[2,3,8]) )
print df_list[ df_list['b'].apply(lambda x:test_any(x,[2,3,8]) ) ]
```

`test_all` return `True` if **all** elements from **data** list are on **expected** list

```
def test_all(data, expected):
    return all( x in expected for x in data )

print df_list['b'].apply(lambda x:test_all(x,[2,3,8]) )
print df_list[ df_list['b'].apply(lambda x:test_all(x,[2,3,8]) ) ]
```

You can swap 'x' and `[2,3,8]`

to get `True` if **any** element from **expected** list is on **data** list

```
print df_list[ df_list['b'].apply(lambda x:test_any_2([2,3,8], x) ) ]
```

to get `True` if **all** elements from **expected** list are on **data** list

```
print df_list[ df_list['b'].apply(lambda x:test_all_2([2,3,8], x) ) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do the following :

```
idx = []

S = [2,3,8]

for i, line in df.iterrows():
     if set(S).issubset(line['b']):
           idx.append(i)
```

Now, you can select only the rows you're interested in :

```
df_subset = df.ix[idx]
```

Comment: @Aidis you can use this in simpler way: `df[ df['b'].apply(lambda x:set(x).issubset([2,3,8])) ]` or with swapped `x` and `[2,3,8]` `df[ df['b'].apply(lambda x:set([2,3,8]).issubset(x)) ]`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I do the following to get your dataframe to a "better" format. I allow for any number of "scientific attributes", as you call them, and will refer to them as "additional".

```
D = df
df = pd.concat([D['a'], pd.DataFrame(D['b'].tolist(), index=D.index)], axis=1, keys=['standard', 'additional'])
In[103]: df
Out[103]: 
   standard  additional      
          a           0  1  2
0         2           2  3  8
```

Now we only search in the "additional" part for the keys that you give us:

```
In[133]: any(df['additional'] == 3, axis=1) & any(df['additional'] == 8, axis=1)
Out[133]: array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

Now I just hack a second fake line to check whether I actually "not select" those that do not fall into the criterion:

```
df2 = df.append(df)
df2.iloc[1] += 1
any(df2['additional'] == 3, axis=1) & any(df2['additional'] == 8, axis=1)
Out[132]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

*Acknowledgement*:
I learned this cute utilization of `concat()` from HYRY [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23884434/1082349).