# Matrix with results of function f(x,y) in Python/numpy/pandas

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas

I have two series X and Y a function f(x,y) in Python. I would like to generate a matrix which contains the output of the function for every combination of X and Y. For instance, if the function was just a simple multiplication, it would look like this:

```
     1   2   3   4   5
   -------------------
1 |  1   2   3   4   5            
2 |  2   4   6   8  10
3 |  3   6   9  12  15
4 |  4   8  12  16  20
5 |  5  10  15  20  25
```

X and Y are actually pairs of coordinates and the function I would like to apply is the vincenty distance from the geopy package.

X and Y are series of a pandas dataframe because I read the data from an excel spreadsheet and I found the pandas read_excel functionality very convenient.

I need to apologize as I feel that this question has been answered already. My problem is that I do not know what this operation is called and what I should look for. What I found are different examples of matrix and vector multiplications, but I do not want to calculate a scalar with the two series.

Thank you very much!

---

I tried to use array broadcasting as suggested, but I am still having a problem:

```
i = np.array(['(-39.736165,-73.238696)', '(-39.765165,-71.230696)', '(-40.736165,-73.230696)'])
j = np.array(['(-38.736165,-73.230696)', '(-35.736165,-73.230696)', '(-41.736165,-73.230696)'])
i = i[:, np.newaxis]
i.shape
(3,1)
PP = vincenty(i, j).meters

>> TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to float
```

---

And another problem: Even if I just want to apply the vincenty formula to the series in my dataframe, I receive an error message:

```
for i in data.index:
print(vincenty((data['X'], data['Y']), (data['Y'], data['Y'])).meters)
>> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The problem is that I have not clue how I get these errors. I can give four single values as coordinates to the vincenty formula or a list or a string and it will work. But the only way I can apply the formula to several entries is using lists.

---

Okay, one final edit ... I could not exactly do what you have suggested. Instead, I converted the pandas series to lists and looped through the lists with the formula. I guess that this is the least efficient way, but that is what I can do with my programming skills and performance does not really matter in my case. However, I appreciate your suggestions (itertools, array broadcasting) and I will keep them in mind for other applications. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/q/23884113/4099598?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I like very much what you can do with array broadcasting, however, there is one more thing ... I actually do not have two inputs for the formula but four (X and Y coordinate for each location). My idea was to have an array with two-dimensional entries, however, I am not sure how to address the first and second entry in the formula ( f(x1,y1,x2,y2) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is this: write function f(x,y) so that it can operate elementwise on Numpy arrays.
For example, if you want to calculate `f(x,y) = x**2 + y**2`, this is

```
def f(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2
```

since power and sum operate elementwise so the expression is OK as it is. Likewise for multiplication:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x*y
```

Then use array broadcasting:

```
x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)  # ensure x, y are Numpy arrays
print f(x[:,np.newaxis], y[np.newaxis,:])
```

https://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting (scroll down a bit for the worked example)

Using itertools with numpy arrays is usually not a good idea performance-wise, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Did you mean `newaxis`?

Comment: Yes, `newaxis`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
itertools.starmap(operator.mul, itertools.product(X,Y))
```

Gives you a generator with the values, which you can reshape and print as you need. Substitute operator.mul with the pertinent function you need to apply.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: this answer is built on the one by pv., and is just a little more than a comment on her/his answer.*

Beware that the way in which you add new axes to your data implies a transposition in the result matrix and what you want to do depends eventually in how you like to read the result, as in algebra (`x` is the row and `y` is the column) or just like a map (`x` is longitude and `y` is latitude)

```
% cat mu.py 
import numpy as np
def f(a,b): return a+10*b

x = np.arange(1,6)
y = np.arange(1,6)

print "inner newaxis"
print x[:,np.newaxis], '\n', y[np.newaxis,:]*10
print f(x[:,np.newaxis], y[np.newaxis,:])

print "outer newaxis"
print x[np.newaxis,:], '\n', y[:,np.newaxis]*10
print f(x[np.newaxis,:], y[:,np.newaxis])
% python mu.py 
inner newaxis
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]] 
[[10 20 30 40 50]]
[[11 21 31 41 51]
 [12 22 32 42 52]
 [13 23 33 43 53]
 [14 24 34 44 54]
 [15 25 35 45 55]]
outer newaxis
[[1 2 3 4 5]] 
[[10]
 [20]
 [30]
 [40]
 [50]]
[[11 12 13 14 15]
 [21 22 23 24 25]
 [31 32 33 34 35]
 [41 42 43 44 45]
 [51 52 53 54 55]]
%
```